# Footer on StackExchange.com links to Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, footer, mso-mse-split

The "[feedback always welcome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)" link in the footer on [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) still links to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

> [image]

It should link to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed at some  point.